# Обновление dataGrid при изменении данных DBContext в отдельном окне с использованием Entity Framework (EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть две таблицы:
*ItemsClothing* {id, name, type}
*ItemsClothing_Storage* {id, name{}, size[A-D], count}

При изменении количества товара из диалогового окна, данные не обновляются в dataGrid. Но при добавление новой сущности в DBContext, dataGrid добавляет новую сущность, но не обновляет изменённые данные.

Инициализация при открытия приложения:

```
        DB.ItemsClothing.Load();
        DB.ItemsClothing_Storage.Load();
        ItemsClothers_Storage_dataGrid_Name.ItemsSource = DB.ItemsClothing.Local;
        ItemsClothers_Storage_dataGrid.ItemsSource = DB.ItemsClothing_Storage.Local;
```

Как реализовать обновление dataGrid при работе с БД из других окон?

Answer (score 0):

Такое часто бывает при работе с `DataGrid`.
Попробуйте очистить `DataGrid` и прочитать в него данные из БД полностью заново. Обычно помогает.